# Clear by user command does not clear all messages by user

Tags: python-3.x, pycord

I was trying to make a command that clears specified number of messages by a particular user, I am new to discord.py, my problem is that the command doesn't clear messages if any other user has sent a message/interrupted messages of the specified user.
Eg:

```
User 1: A
User 2: B
User 1: A
User 1: A
```

I try to clear 3 messages by user 1, but it clears only the last 2 and not the one that comes before User 2 sent a message. Here's my code:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Clears messages by a specified user.')
async def user_clear(ctx,amount:int, member:discord.Member):
  def check(message):
    return message.author==member
  await ctx.channel.purge(check=check,limit=amount)
  await ctx.respond(f"Cleared {amount} messages by {member}!")
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: what does `f"Cleared {amount} messages by {member}!"` evaluate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one which works:

```
@bot.command()
async def user_clear(ctx: commands.Context, amount: int, member: discord.Member = None):
    counter = 0
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=100, before=ctx.message):
        if counter < amount and message.author == member:
            await message.delete()
            counter += 1

    await ctx.channel.send(f"Cleared {amount} messages by {member}!")
```